# Nutch how to crawl but not index the site navigation (w/ Solr)

Tags: solr, nutch

While I feel this should be a standard procedure, I am not really finding anything via searching that gives a good indication of how one might exlude site navigation menu content from the content that Nutch indexes to Solr during a crawl.

That is, I am seeing the navigation menu text in all content that is getting indexed and this damages search because then all content will have the same text in it. Obviously I want to keep using the site navigation for crawling, but I don't want it indexed. Is there a best practice for accomplishing this with Nutch? Like a way to wrap the navigation in some kind of tag `<!-- NO_NUTCH_IDX -->`, for example?

I am new to Nutch (obviously) so I don't know the best place that this would be accomplished.

thanks very much.

Comment: What you probably need is https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NUTCH-585

Comment: thanks, that looks very much like what i've described. though i wonder if it is still relevant for nutch 1.5 - thanks I'll look at it :-)